# How to deploy older ingress-nginx-controller or specify version with minikube?

Tags: kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, kvm, nginx-ingress

I am trying to deploy a specific version of `ingress-controller` with minikube and kubernetesv1.13, but from what I see it is only possible to have latest version of ingress-nginx-controller deployed.

I expect the `ingress-nginx-controller-#####-####` pod to come back online and run with the nginx-ingress image version I point to in the deployments details.

After editing the ingress-nginx-controller deployment via `kubectl edit` and changing the `image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller` property from `0.32.0` to `0.24.1`, the pod restarts and goes into `CrashLoopBackOff` state.

By hitting describe, the pod seems complaining about the node not having free ports:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                     From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                    ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  5m8s (x2 over 5m8s)     default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports.
  Normal   Scheduled         4m54s                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/ingress-nginx-controller-6c4b64d58c-s5ddz to minikube
```

After searching for a [similar case](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66568) I tried the following:
I check `ss` but see no port 80 or 443 being busy on the host:

```
State                Recv-Q                Send-Q                               Local Address:Port                               Peer Address:Port               Process               
LISTEN               0                     32                                   192.168.122.1:53                                      0.0.0.0:*                                        
LISTEN               0                     4096                                 127.0.0.53%lo:53                                      0.0.0.0:*                                        
LISTEN               0                     5                                        127.0.0.1:631                                     0.0.0.0:*                                        
LISTEN               0                     5                                            [::1]:631                                        [::]:*
```

No pods seems to be in `terminating` status:

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-86c58d9df4-7s55r                    1/1     Running            1          3h14m
coredns-86c58d9df4-rtssn                    1/1     Running            1          3h14m
etcd-minikube                               1/1     Running            1          3h13m
ingress-nginx-admission-create-gpfml        0/1     Completed          0          47m
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-z96hd         0/1     Completed          0          47m
ingress-nginx-controller-6c4b64d58c-s5ddz   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9          24m
kube-apiserver-minikube                     1/1     Running            0          145m
kube-controller-manager-minikube            1/1     Running            0          145m
kube-proxy-pmwxr                            1/1     Running            0          144m
kube-scheduler-minikube                     1/1     Running            0          145m
storage-provisioner                         1/1     Running            2          3h14m
```

I did not create any yml file or custom deployment, just installed minikube and enabled the ingress addon.

How to use a different nginx-ingress-controller version ?

Comment: Hello, which version of minikube are you using? and why the latest nginx ingress version is not an option for you?

Comment: Hi willrof, thanks for supporting. I am using minikube v.1.11.0. I need ingress-controller 0.24.1 in order to replicate a production environment on a small scale.

Answer (score 1):

- The Nginx Version is tied to minikube version.
- First I tried previous versions. Unfortunatelly, the available Minikube v1.3 uses nginx 0.25.0 and Minikube v1.2 uses nginx 0.23.0
- So the only way I found to run nginx 0.24.0 in Minikube was building the binary myself using minikube v1.4, here is the step-by-step:
- Download the minikube 1.4 repository and extract it:

```
$ wget https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/archive/v1.4.0.tar.gz

$ tar -xvzf v1.4.0.tar.gz
```

- Then, cd into the newly created `minikube-1.4.0` folder and edit the file `deploy/addons/ingress/ingress-dp.yaml.tmpl` changing the image version to 0.24.1 as below:

```
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.24.1
```

- In order to build you have to download a Go distribution from original repo: https://golang.org/dl/
- then follow the steps in https://golang.org/doc/install to install it. If you are running linux 64 bits, you can use the bellow comments:

```
$ wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.14.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.14.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz 
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

- Then from the `Minikube 1.4.0` folder, run `make`:

```
/minikube-1.4.0$ ls
CHANGELOG.md        CONTRIBUTING.md  go.mod  images      Makefile      OWNERS     SECURITY_CONTACTS  test.sh
cmd                 deploy           go.sum  installers  netlify.toml  pkg        site               third_party
code-of-conduct.md  docs             hack    LICENSE     README.md     test       translations

/minikube-1.4.0$ make
```

- It may take a few minutes to download all dependencies, then let's copy the freshly build binary to `/usr/local/bin` and deploy minikube:

```
/minikube-1.4.0$ cd out/

/minikube-1.4.0/out$ ls
minikube  minikube-linux-amd64

$ sudo cp minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube

$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.4.0

$ minikube start --vm-driver=kvm2 --kubernetes-version 1.13.12
```

**NOTE:** if you get an error about kvm2 driver when starting minikube, run the following command:

```
$ curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/docker-machine-driver-kvm2 && sudo install docker-machine-driver-kvm2 /usr/local/bin/
```

- This version comes with ingress enabled by default, let's check the deployment status:

```
$ minikube addons list | grep ingress
- ingress: enabled

$ kubectl describe deploy nginx-ingress-controller -n kube-system |
 grep Image:
    Image:       quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.24.1

$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-54ff9cd656-d95w5                 1/1     Running   0          2m14s
coredns-54ff9cd656-tnvnw                 1/1     Running   0          2m14s
etcd-minikube                            1/1     Running   0          78s
kube-addon-manager-minikube              1/1     Running   0          71s
kube-apiserver-minikube                  1/1     Running   0          71s
kube-controller-manager-minikube         1/1     Running   0          78s
kube-proxy-wj2d6                         1/1     Running   0          2m14s
kube-scheduler-minikube                  1/1     Running   0          87s
nginx-ingress-controller-f98c6df-5h2l7   1/1     Running   0          2m9s
storage-provisioner                      1/1     Running   0          2m8s
```

As you can see, the pod `nginx-ingress-controller-f98c6df-5h2l7` is in running state.

If you have any question let me know in the comments.